# Why do I not have an option to enable VNC?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, vnc

From most of the sources I've read, I should be able to start my RPI and go:

`Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration` and select the interfaces tab.  Here should be the option to enable / disable VNC.  The problem is that I don't have this option.  When I look here, VNC does not appear on this tab!!

It isn't clear however, whether the VNC option on the interfaces tab is the server or the client so I don't know whether I need this option or not.

Something must be installed as when I try to connect using RealVNC from my PC, I get an error saying the client actively refused the connection.

I am using `2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old image of raspbian. The newest was released a few weeks ago and has been updated to debian stretch. Download the newest image from the raspberry pi [downloads](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) page and mount the image to an sd card (I recommend [Etcher](https://etcher.io/), works on windows, mac and linux). It will come with ssh and vnc disabled by default go to the interfaces tab in raspberry config menu.